# Generate all size of android icon

Tags: android

I want know, is any tool is available to generate all size android icon.
Like hdpi, lpdi, xxhdpi , xxxhdpi

Generate all type on icon from tool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below link.
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

For material icon you can use Material icon generator plugin in android studio

Answer (score 10):

You can make use of Android Studio. Right Click on your project->New->Image Asset and select your icon. Studio will automatically create all the required sized icons for you.

Comment: The best solution!

Comment: This's the most convenient **but** (till now, see last edit date) it has a fixed size for custom icons. Use another would be better in this case.

Comment: Now, in the latest versions, not able to generate background transparent icons. If we select Launcher Icon(Legacy Only), and Shape as none, a background will be added as svg. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Image resizer . Easy and simple : [Final Android Resizer](https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer)