# What's the best way to create icon for an android app

Tags: android, icons

I have a sample android application codebase. I want 
to change the app icon when it's installed on the android phone
I see that under a folder there are 5 different types of icons
listed 1. hdpi 2. mdpi 3. xhdpi 4. xxhdpi 5. xxxhdpi
I want to change the icon. Where can I search for available 
android icons and get all these different sizes for it?
Is there any good recommended resource for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate all size of android icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479325/generate-all-size-of-android-icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the icon as a jpg, then go to the mipmap folder, right click on it, click on new image asset, and after making suitable modifications (optional), click next, click finish. All the variants will be automatically generated.

Comment: Thanks That worked. But I have a question. When I created a new image asset it automatically generated a new folder. So now there is two folders under the `mipmap` and it seems android studio automatically picked the latest one. How did that happen? Probably I can delete the older image asset

Comment: Oh yes. You should delete the old one.

Comment: You see there will be vector assets named ic_launcher.xml in the anydpi folder. They are important. So you should just consider deleting the default image assets and then name your new assets ic_launcher

Answer (score 0):

In android studio; right click on the drawable folder then new, then vector assets. it will pop up a dialogue box, there you will see all the options.